# Trying to install linux headers 2204

Tags: linux-headers

Trying to install linux headers for Ubuntu 2204 Desktop (uname -r = 5.13.0-40-generic) and I get:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source  
E: Package 'linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic' has no installation candidate
```

What is the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're running 22.04? The kernel version should be 5.15 ... 

Comment: Yep, downloaded ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso, created usb, and did an update via sudo update-manager -d
Please tell me if that is incorrect way to do it...
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Answer (score 2):

You upgraded from an older release. Please try installing current kernel with ist headers by `sudo apt install linux-generic`. (It is probably already installed already.) Then reboot to start using that kernel.

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. Yes, when I sudo apt install linux-generic I get "already installed", but when I try to install the headers, get "E: Package 'linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic' has no installation candidate"

Comment: Think I have it sussed...
Am dual-booting with Tumbleweed, and hadn't updated grub.